# Web API - Class variables retained across requests in class inheriting AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute

I'm trying to implement custom AuthorizeAttribute. In the sample code below, when entering the IsAuthorized method, the variable moduleId retains the value of the last request. I was expecting a separate object for each request and hence the value should be null.

```
Public Class MyAuthorizeAttribute    
Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Private moduleId As String   'This is variable has previous requests value

    Protected Overrides Function IsAuthorized(actionContext As HttpActionContext) As Boolean    
        moduleId = actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("moduleId")    
        'check if user has access to module    
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

On AppStart the custom authorize attribute is applied to all api requests.

```
Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    config.Filters.Add(New MyAuthorizeAttribute())
End Sub
```

The same behaviour is experienced for custom ActionFilterAttribute as well.

My question is,

1. Why is this happening?
2. Will this impact when there are hundreds of simultaneous requests? If yes, how could I overcome this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same filter instance is used for all requests, so you cannot use property.

Instead, you want to use local variable.

```
Dim moduleId As String = actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("moduleId")
```